# Insert code after the third item in the wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out a way of injecting some code after ever x items in the wordpress loop. So, for example this could be to add an advert after every three posts displayed on a page.

Is this possible in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your WP loop looks something like this:

```
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
```

You would have to do something like:

```
$i = 0;
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      $i++;

      if (($i % 3) == 0) :
        echo 'This the third post';
      endif;

      the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Upvoted for the correct answer, despite OP's question not indicating sufficient research into the problem or attempted code examples.